# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Freelancing Stack Exchange](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Should freelancers seek long-term clients or not?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/should-freelancers-seek-long-term-clients-or-not)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Bad rating has decreased my chances of getting work - How can I recover from bad feedback?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/bad-rating-has-decreased-my-chances-of-getting-work-how-can-i-recover-from-bad)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it required to register under any authorities to work as a freelancer?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/is-it-required-to-register-under-any-authorities-to-work-as-a-freelancer)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it up to the Contractor, or the Employer to provide the 1099?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/is-it-up-to-the-contractor-or-the-employer-to-provide-the-1099)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to get work on freelancer.com as an existing contractor but new to freelancer.com?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/how-to-get-work-on-freelancer-com-as-an-existing-contractor-but-new-to-freelance)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Choosing the right partners](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/choosing-the-right-partners)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Which collaborative software do you usually need to work?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/which-collaborative-software-do-you-usually-need-to-work)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can I charge customer at my installation rate for the time it takes me to figure out the bill?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/can-i-charge-customer-at-my-installation-rate-for-the-time-it-takes-me-to-figure)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much cost can be charged for an hour in web development.?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-much-cost-can-be-charged-for-an-hour-in-web-development)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to determine the price for an app to run over Android and iOs?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-to-determine-the-price-for-an-app-to-run-over-android-and-ios)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

**Question**: [Is it up to the Contractor, or the Employer to provide the 1099?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/is-it-up-to-the-contractor-or-the-employer-to-provide-the-1099)

---

*1099 contractor or employer who provides*
Google search: last result on Page 1

*who provides 1099 contractor employer*
Google search: halfway on Page 2

---

Considering that the first few results are IRS sites, I think we're doing alright on this question. I did notice, though, that results varied greatly between Google and Bing (which wasn't nearly as successful)

Comment: But who actually uses Bing? :)

Answer (score 2):

**Question**: [Which collaborative software do you usually need to work?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/which-collaborative-software-do-you-usually-need-in-you-work)

---

*useful collaborative software for freelancers*
Google search: 2nd result on Page 1

*collaborative software for freelancers*
Google search: 4th result on Page 1 (up from 5th whilst I was researching this answer)

*useful collaborative software*
Google search: first result on Page 3

---

Top result on first 2 searches is really useful list of tools but to answer the question in that way would be to make it a polling question, which is not allowed on SE sites.